# Телеграм бот aiogram + motor, ошибка при поиске пользователя, бесконечный поиск

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, pymongo

Проблема программы в бесконечном поиске пользователя при вызове find_one.
Код database:

```
import os

import motor.motor_asyncio
from datetime import datetime
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(os.getenv("MYSQL"))
db = client['BOTDATA']
collection = db['DATASET']
async def do_on_start(user_id):
    document = {
        "_id": user_id,
        "data": str(datetime.now())
    }
    await collection.insert_one(document)
    print(document)
async def find_id(user_id):
    print(collection.find_one({"_id": user_id}))
    if collection.find_one({"_id": user_id}) == 0:
        await do_on_start(user_id)
    else:
        return 0
```

Обрывок кода main:

```
import database as db

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def on_start(message: types.Message):
    await db.find_id(message.from_user.id)
    if message.from_user.id == ME:
        await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, добро пожаловать', reply_markup=main_admin)
    else:
        await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, добро пожаловать', reply_markup=main)
```

Ошибка: <Future pending cb=[_chain_future.._call_check_cancel() at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\futures.py:384]>